# Using node_module (website scraper) in Angular 4 failes on usage

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, node-modules

Currently I’m trying to add the node_module “website scraper” [1] to my Angular 4 project.
I download and install the module by “npm install website-scraper –save”. 
In my Component I import the module by “import * as Scraper  from 'website-scraper’”.

Until now everything compiles as expected. 
If I now simply add “console.log(Scraper)” somewhere to my component, I get warnings [3] and my my Browser throws errors [2]

Can somebody enlighten me, what is going wrong? I use node 8.9.0 and npm 5.5.1. Anyway I tried multiple furhter (older) versions of node and npm resulting in the same behaviour. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```
[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/website-scraper

[2] graceful-fs.js:166 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at patch (graceful-fs.js:166)
    at Object.eval (graceful-fs.js:27)
    at eval (graceful-fs.js:262)
    at Object.../../../../graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js (vendor.bundle.js:884)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (index.js:4)
    at Object.../../../../fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js (vendor.bundle.js:726)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (index.js:8)
    at Object.../../../../fs-extra/lib/index.js (vendor.bundle.js:734)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.eval (index.js:6)
    at eval (index.js:69)
    at Object.../../../../website-scraper/lib/resource-saver/index.js (vendor.bundle.js:3110)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (scraper.js:16) 


[3]: WARNING in ./node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv/lib/async.js
119:15-28 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    at CommonJsRequireContextDependency.getWarnings (C:\Users\XY\XYZ\MyProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\ContextDependency.js:39:18)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (C:\Users\XY\XYZ\MyProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:703:24)
    at Compilation.finish (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:561:9)
    at applyPluginsParallel.err (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:506:17)
    at C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:289:11
    at _addModuleChain (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:507:11)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:477:14)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 @ ./node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv/lib/async.js
 @ ./node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js
 @ ./node_modules/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/website-scraper/lib/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/website-scraper/lib/scraper.js
 @ ./src/app/mytest/mytest.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/index.js
13:21-34 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    at CommonJsRequireContextDependency.getWarnings (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\ContextDependency.js:39:18)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:703:24)
    at Compilation.finish (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:561:9)
    at applyPluginsParallel.err (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:506:17)
    at C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:289:11
    at _addModuleChain (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:507:11)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:477:14)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 @ ./node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv/lib/compile/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js
 @ ./node_modules/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/website-scraper/lib/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/website-scraper/lib/scraper.js
 @ ./src/app/mytest/mytest.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv/lib/async.js
96:20-33 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
    at CommonJsRequireContextDependency.getWarnings (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\ContextDependency.js:39:18)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:703:24)
    at Compilation.finish (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:561:9)
    at applyPluginsParallel.err (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:506:17)
    at C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:289:11
    at _addModuleChain (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:507:11)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (C:\Users\MyUser\MyProject\A1\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:477:14)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 @ ./node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv/lib/async.js
 @ ./node_modules/har-validator/node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js
 @ ./node_modules/har-validator/lib/node4/promise.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/website-scraper/lib/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/website-scraper/lib/scraper.js
 @ ./src/app/mytest/mytest.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: you should also install https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/website-scraper.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for mentioning. I already did so, unfortunately Things didnt change (With the exception of Code autocompletion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add `website-scraper` directly to your Angular project because it is for server-side usage with nodejs only.

I can suggest to use it on server side and return results to client. 
Here is an example of how to use `website-scraper` on server with nodejs and express and angular 1 on client side: https://github.com/website-scraper/demo

Comment: Thx alot, i really confused this one. I am really greateful, that you cleared this topic.